# How do I send an httpOnly cookie to the server?

Tags: node.js, authorization

I set an httpOnly cookies in the browser every time a use logs in or signs up to my website. The cookie contains the refresh token which I use to get a new access token. But the problem is that that refresh token is not sent to the server in any request by default.
I just want to know what should I do to sent the httpOnly cookie to the server with every request.
I am using the MERN stack.

Comment: Let me see how you're sending your cookie from the server. As you're using ajax that will not automatically save the cookie response in the browser. So basically you aren't setting the cookie.

Comment: @Sun Podder I am setting the cookie by res.cookie method in node js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A couple reasons this might happen, any or multiple of these can cause your issue:

- You are setting the cookie `secure`, but not viewing the page over https. The point in `secure` cookies is they only get sent over a secure connection (ie. https), so you probably don't want this in development (but you *do* want this in production).
- You are setting the cookie as `SameSite`, but the page the request is sent from is not the same as the cookie origin.
- The cookie is not even set. You can check this in the Application tab in the Developer Tools of your browser. This can happen if the cookie would have been set as a result of a CORS request.
- If you are using CORS, you need to use `withCredentials` so the cookies are also sent (or `credentials: 'include'` for ES6 Fetch API).

Comment: yes I am using cors and have set the "credentials" property as well. I can see the httpOnly cookie in the response sent by the server and I have not used the secure flag. But when I see the application tab, there are no cookies set in the application tab. Now what should I do

Comment: @ChiefJalal just clicking on the cookie option will not show the cookies. click the ▷ (arrow) button beside the cookies option to show all domain that have cookies, then click on that domain to view all the cookies for that domain

Answer (score 0):

`httponly` can't be accessed via the browser application tab "for security reasons". You only get them as a response. If u are using axios this will help:

```js
axios.get(`API_URL`, { withCredentials: true }).then((response) => {
  return response.data;
});
```

Your backend will be something like this:

```js
const getAccessToken = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.refreshtoken || null
        console.log(token)
        if (!token) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please login now!" })
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please login now!" })
            //  const access_token = createToken({ id: user.id }, "15m")
            res.json({ token })
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
    }
}
```